# when is shuffling data required, and why padded_batch here?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm learning NLP and this code:

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import tensorflow as tf
dataset, info = tfds.load('imdb_reviews/subwords8k', with_info=True, as_supervised=True)
train_dataset, test_dataset = dataset['train'], dataset['test']
BUFFER_SIZE = 10000
BATCH_SIZE = 64

train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE)
train_dataset = train_dataset.padded_batch(BATCH_SIZE, tf.compat.v1.data.get_output_shapes(train_dataset))
test_dataset = test_dataset.padded_batch(BATCH_SIZE, tf.compat.v1.data.get_output_shapes(test_dataset))
```

How do you tell when you have to shuffle the data and when you don't have to?

And why is padded_batch there rather than pad_sequences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shuffle the data when your data has some sort of order. Like one of the feature in your dataset may have some order like ascending or descending. Generally, you don't pass ordered data to your model as it affects the gradient values and losses and makes it difficult to converge. It's always a good idea to shuffle your data before using it.

train_dataset is a tf.data.Dataset object. The object has an inbuilt method to padded_batch. So when you iterate over the train_dataset you will get padded batch as output.

You can also use pad_sequences instead but for that, you have iterate over the dataset and apply pad_sequences to each output batch. So in essence you have to use one extra step which can be avoided by using padded batch.

Note: Both carry out similar function.

Comment: Can you plz accept and upvote if the solution worked.

Comment: What does batch mean in this case? (is it the batch processing, ie n batches per epoch) and why do we want to set it in batches in this case?

Comment: When you set batch_size it will provide an output based on the batch_size. Let's say you have data of 100 samples and you converted this data into tf.dataset with batch_size argument as 10. Then when you iterate over the dataset using for loop, the loop will run for 10 iterations and in each iteration, you will get 10 examples from your data.